# How can I convert my json response to nested json where attributes are under another 'attribute'?

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django APIs. I am designing a api where response will be like this after a post request:

```
{ "set_attributes":
    {
      "name": "some value",
      "age": "another value"
    },
}
```

At present my response showing like this:

```
{
  "Name": "some value",
  "age": "another value"
}
```

I am using class based views and for forms I am using Django models. I did not render any html forms.

serializers.py:

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    Name = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    Birthdate = serializers.DateField(default=datetime.now())

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ('Name', 'Birthdate', 'age')

class ListingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    age = serializers.Field(source='age')
```

models.py

```
class Contact(models.Model):

    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    Birthdate = models.DateField(default=datetime.now())

    age = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.Birthdate > date.today():
            raise ValidationError("The date cannot be in the future!")
        super(Contact, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def age(self):
        today = date.today()
        birth = self.Birthdate
        newage = today.year - birth.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (birth.month, birth.day))
        return newage

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
```

views.py

```
class ContactList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer

class ContactDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):

    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer
```

Comment: What's your current code that produces your current result…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to_representation() method to display your attributes in a nested json under another attribute.

For this you have to edit your views.py by adding to_representation() method in this order:

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

Name = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
Birth_year = serializers.IntegerField(default=2022)

class Meta:
    model = Contact
    fields = ('Name','Birthdate','age')

def to_representation(self, instance):
    response = {
        "set_attributes" : super().to_representation(instance),
    }
    return response

 class ListingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 age = serializers.Field(source='age')
```

Implementing the .to_representation(self, value) method takes the target of the field as the value argument, and should return the representation that should be used to serialize the target. The value argument will typically be a model instance.

This is the output:

```
{ "set_attributes" :

 {
   "name": "some value",
   "Birthdate": 2005/4/24,
   "age": 17
 },
}
```

Hope it helped.